# Narrator not detecting international voices

Tags: c#, windows-7, text-to-speech, narrator

Apologies for asking a question that will more than likely have a simple answer but this is truly my last resort.

My problem, so far, is that narrator is only detecting English voices, even though i have installed additional voices in other languages.

[image: Narrator only detecting English voices]

As you can see the only two voices are detected, they are in both in English. This is strange because a program called TextAloud detects all my voices them effortlessly.

[image]

Im am trying to integrate a Korean voice into my C# program and right now it will only allow me to use the voices that Narrator detects...

```
            foreach (InstalledVoice voice in speechSynthesizer.GetInstalledVoices())
            {
                VoiceInfo info = voice.VoiceInfo;
                Console.WriteLine(" Voice Name: " + info.Name);
            }
```

This code should detect the installed additional voices but only detects Narrators English voices as installed!

so, my question, How can i make Narrator detect all my installed voices?

Comment: If you run your app as administrator, does it show them?

Comment: @John-Koerner No... it does not show... it only shows the Voices available in the narrator window.

Comment: Have you tried using the `GetInstalledVoices` overload that accepts a culture and specifying the Korean culture?

Comment: @John I tried the parsing a culture tag to the GetInstalledVoices method, using CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("ko-KR"), Still no luck.

Comment: Are you sure that your voices are Sapi 5.3 voices?  The voice registration is different between SAPI 4 (XP) and SAPI 5.  Moreover, TextAloud explicitly supports both SAPI 4 and SAPI 5 voices (where Narrator does not).